# Pandas datfaframe, how to order a column grouped by 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this one, with many more rows:

| zone | keyword | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nyc1 | iphone | 10 |
| nyc1 | smart tv | 6 |
| nyc1 | iphone | 12 |
| nyc2 | laptop | 22 |
| slc1 | iphone | 3 |
| slc2 | radio | 5 |
| la1 | iphone | 10 |
| la1 | tablet | 22 |
| la1 | tablet | 5 |

How can I get another dataframe where for each zone/keyword I get the sum of the sales column (grouped by zone/keyword) in descending order?
For this example it should look like this (I don't want to reorder based on the other 2 columns, only sales):

| zone | keyword | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nyc1 | iphone | 22 |
| nyc1 | smart tv | 6 |
| nyc2 | laptop | 22 |
| slc1 | iphone | 3 |
| slc2 | radio | 5 |
| la1 | tablet | 27 |
| la1 | iphone | 10 |

I already grouped the columns using

```
df_sales = df_sales.groupby(['zone','keyword'])['sales'].sum()
```

But the result is a series with the sum-of-sales column not in order.

Using reset_index and sort_values does order by sales, but removes the groupby and order the whole dataframe...

```
.reset_index().sort_values('sales', ascending=False)
```

How can I get a dataframe like the one above?

Comment: Omit `reset_index`.

Comment: without the reset_index I get "ValueError: No axis named sales for object type Series"

Answer (score 0):

After you complete your groupby, you can use `sort_values`

```
df_sales = df_sales.groupby(['zone','keyword'])['sales'].sum()
sorted_df = df_sales.sort_values(by=['zone'])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: i get this error in the sort:  sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

Answer (score 0):

```
df_sales.groupby(['zone','keyword'])['sales'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('sales', ascending=False)
```

reset_index reverts series back to dataframe and after that you can sort values.

Comment: This does revert to a dataframe, but this reorders the whole dataframe by "sales", removing the group by...

Answer (score 0):

**soulution 1** : using `agg(sum)`

To get `DataFrame` object instead, use double square brackets around `sales`.

```
df_sales = df_sales.groupby(['zone','keyword'])[['sales']].agg('sum').reset_index()
```

**soulution 2** : using `sum()`

```
df_sales = df_sales.groupby(['zone','keyword'])['sales'].sum().reset_index()
```